# Metabox with checkbox is not updating

Tags: metabox, save-post

I trying to set a meta_box with a single checkbox, everything goes fine, however if I uncheck it and save the post, it marks again as checked, I've been taking a look but I cannot find my mistake.

Take a look a my code.

```
function am_checkbox_option() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $front_event = $custom["front_event"][0];
    wp_nonce_field(__FILE__, 'am_front_event');
    if ( $front_event ) {
        $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
    } else {
        $checked = "";
    }
?>
    <label>Display Content? (type yes):</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="front_event" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
<?php
        }
}

add_action('save_post', function() {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    global $post;

    if ( $_POST && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['am_front_event'], __FILE__) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['front_event']) ) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_event', $_POST['front_event']);
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is code I have used before - the main difference looks to me that you are checking if the meta exists rather than what it's value is to determine if it should be checked.

```
// Checkbox Meta
add_action("admin_init", "checkbox_init");

function checkbox_init(){
  add_meta_box("checkbox", "Checkbox", "checkbox", "post", "normal", "high");
}

function checkbox(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $field_id = $custom["field_id"][0];
 ?>

  <label>Check for yes</label>
  <?php $field_id_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', true);
  if($field_id_value == "yes") $field_id_checked = 'checked="checked"'; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_id" value="yes" <?php echo $field_id_checked; ?> />
  <?php

}

// Save Meta Details
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;

if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post->ID;
}

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "field_id", $_POST["field_id"]);
}
```

Comment: Use the `add_meta_boxes` action for adding metaboxes(it's there specifically for that), as per the example on the `add_metabox` codex page. You'll also benefit in getting the post type and post object passed to the callback.

Answer (score 15):

simple add an else clause to delete the post meta if not checked and your code will do just fine, so change :

```
if ( isset($_POST['front_event']) ) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_event', $_POST['front_event']);
}
```

to

```
if ( isset($_POST['front_event']) ) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_event', $_POST['front_event']);
}else{
    delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'front_event');
}
```

Comment: if the checkbox is unchecked, it will not be in the $_POST array, it's only sent when checked, hence why the else statement works.